# trying to load a bitmap, but xna want´s a Texture2D

Tags: xna

I'm currently trying to load a simple bitmap using XNA but I get the following error:

> Error loading "Maps\standard". File contains Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D but trying to load as System.Drawing.Bitmap.

code:

```
public Bitmap map;

public void load(Game game, String image) {
    path = image; //path to image
    map = game.Content.Load<Bitmap>("Maps/"+path);
    sizeX = map.Width;
    sizeY = map.Height;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the Bitmap file once loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You want the below:

```
map = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Maps/"+path);
```

The way XNA works is that there is a content pipeline, which takes inputs (like your bitmap image) and produces outputs (the `Texture2D`), which is in a different format to the input.

XNA works with a `Texture2D` object when displaying images.

Comment: Why do you want a bitmap? If you *do* want a bitmap then don't use XNA to load it.

Comment: @Hobbit9797 A Texture2D is just like a bitmap. It has a 2D data array that stores the values of the texture as a grid of pixels. XNA doesn't directly support using a bitmap.

Comment: @Hobbit9797 You can write data from a Bitmap to a Texture2D with the [`SetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.setdata(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) method. But loading it through the content pipeline will probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I just use the C# standard

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose it once you're finished with it: `bmp.Dispose()'